# get the current content of codemirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I'd like to save the current content of a codemirror editor using a php script. I used the following codes in the hope when clicking on a button the current content will be passed to the php script. The scripts below has been edited and worked.

```
var test = code.getValue();
```

but this does not  reflect the change in the editor.

```
<script language = "Javascript">
function saveData() {
        var test = editor.getValue();  
    new Ajax.Request('savedata.php', {
    method: 'post',
    parameters: {
        test: test,
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

The editor is constructed using:
    ;

```
<script>
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    lineWrapping: true,
    extraKeys: {"F11": toggleFullscreenEditing, "Esc": toggleFullscreenEditing},
    onBlur: function(){editor.save()}
});
```

Any comments or suggestions are highly appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last code with editor ... You have to put in a function and call it after changing the text area - maybe with `OnBlur=""`.

Comment: Thanks. The following works    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
        lineNumbers: true,
        lineWrapping: true,
        extraKeys: {"F11": toggleFullscreenEditing, "Esc": toggleFullscreenEditing},
        onBlur: function(){editor.save()}
    });

Answer (score 3):

Note that the CodeMirror's event api has changed (see [CodeMirror doc](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#events))

So the above should be something like:

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
  lineNumbers: true,
  lineWrapping: true,
  extraKeys: {"F11": toggleFullscreenEditing, "Esc": toggleFullscreenEditing},
});

editor.on("blur": function(){editor.save();});
```

Comment: +1, Thanks for the update, please note it's editor.on("blur", function(){editor.save();}); (ie a , not a :)

Answer (score 0):

this will also work:

```
document.querySelector('.CodeMirror').CodeMirror.setValue('some text');
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.